# vba - select first worksheet in a csv file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that pastes some data into a large number of csv files saved in a folder.  How do I get the macro to select the first worksheet in each csv file (csv files only have one worksheet)? If it was an Excel file I could do this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
```

However, each csv file has a different name for the worksheet.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to it by its index instead of by name:

```
Sheets(1).Select
```